# Nginx Redirects to Wrong URL

Tags: nginx

I have following Nginx configuration:

```
server {
   listen 8080 default_server;
   listen [::]:8080 default_server;
   ...

   error_page 401 = @login;
   location @login {
       return 302 https://$http_host/logon?continueURL=https://$http_host;
   }

   location /logon {
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Connection "";
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_pass http://${UPSTREAM_URL}$request_uri;
   }
...
}
```

UPSTREAM_URL configured in Docker file.
The problem is that when I have 401 error Nginx redirects to https://localhost:8080/logon?continueURL=https://localhost:8080 instead of `http://${UPSTREAM_URL}$request_uri`

Docker image is `nginx:alpine`

What should I change in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

```
`location @login {
   return 302 https://$http_host/logon?continueURL=https://$http_host;
```

} ` this line is doing the redirection

Comment: yes, I expect it to redirect to `location @login` and then to `location /logon`

Comment: I did what you suggested and it redirects to the same URL (localhost:8080/logon?continueURL=....) but with 504 HTTP error Gateway Timeout